# Errors /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb

Tags: mysql

After some messing around and uninstalling mariadb-server, I have problem installing mysql-server:

```
root@serv:#  apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,836 kB of archives.
After this operation, 32.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 437852 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb) ...
Aborting downgrade from (at least) 10.1 to 5.5.
If are sure you want to downgrade to 5.5, remove the file
/var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag and try installing again.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried

```
apt-get --purge remove mysql-server
```

and

```
apt-get -f install
```

and

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

but it resulted the same error. Appreciate your hint to resolve this and install mysql-server.

Comment: Did below answer help?  If yes, care to accept???  ;)

Answer (score 2):

As per your error log, do a:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/mysql/debian-*.flag
```

and then install again!

Comment: @Marslo: thanks for the upvote!  Happy MMXVII! **;-)**

Comment: happy new year 2017!